# can filebeat monitor file content changed

Tags: filebeat

I have a csv file which is to indicate the something states.
like:
pid,male,money
p1,man,23
p2,woman,45

and the states in the file will change. sometimes add, sometimes update.
so can filebeat monitor the update behavior of the file ?

as my test.
when I manually update the file and save it.
filebeat will send all file content to downstream.
if i use process to do it, it can not sensitive the updates.

here is my filebeat config.

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: filestream
  id: alpha-fund
  paths:
    - file_path
  encoding: gbk
  exclude_lines: ['^xx', '^xxxx' ]
  ignore_older: 24h
  fields:
    kafka_key: xxx

output.console:
  pretty: true
```

give me a way to monitor the updates of file.